# Using GULP to set up font awesome in ASP.NET 5 BETA 8

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, bower

According to this site http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/06/29/the-power-of-bower-with-asp-net-5-0.aspx and specifially this image here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-56-73/6114.Gulp_2D00_js.PNG

I am suppose to haven an array that I can modify, but with beta8 I dont see this in my gulpfile.js below is my gulp file.

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />

var gulp = require("gulp"),
rimraf = require("rimraf"),
concat = require("gulp-concat"),
cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
project = require("./project.json");

var paths = {
webroot: "./" + project.webroot + "/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(".")); 
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

I will assume that things have chanced since that article is written.
I simply would like to get bower/gulp to integrate font awesome into my web project, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at the following url.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx